# have a temperature vs have a fever

Tags: difference

the definitions of "to have a temperature" and "to have a fever" in the dictionary are similar,

So can I say that these two have the same meaning?

I've got a fever/ a temperature.

Comment: The ordinary phrase is _have a temperature._ I might say _I have a fever_ if I was explaining to somebody official why I couldn't be present at something; but with people I know, even bosses, I would say _I've got a temperature_.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Of course everyone and everything has a measurable temperature, but the idiom "to have a temperature" means exactly "to have a fever," that is to say an **abnormally high** temperature.

Comment: It might just be me, but I perceive "have a temperature" as less serious than "have a fever."  Not that they represent different conditions, but rather a different emphasis or characterization of the same condition.

Comment: @Juhasz I would agree with you. Probably a dialect difference between us and Colin Fine.

Answer (score 2):

No. Lexico differentiates them by severity and formality.

> [**temperature**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/temperature)
> **1.2** *informal* A body temperature above the normal.

and

> [**fever**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fever)
> **1** An abnormally high body temperature, usually accompanied by shivering, headache, and in severe instances, delirium.

For me, the difference is that a 'temperature' is inconvenient or uncomfortable, whereas a 'fever' is incapacitating. If someone says "I can't attend, I have a temperature" I might think [*man flu*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/man_flu).